# Query which involves 4 tables, inner join?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am just developing a PHP aplication, and I need a query which involves 4 tables. tables are like:

```
news {news_pk, user, description, building_pk}
building {building_pk, area_pk, description}
area {area_pk,state_pk}
states {state_pk, name}
```

I would like to show results filtered by state name (or what I think is the same `state_pk`).
I would like to show news from a certain state.

I am not using MySQL so often, but in this app I am doing several queries like this and I am not sure if the **inner join** is a good solution.

Which query could be the most effective to show only news from a certain state?

Comment: Yes, JOINS are good solutions for your problem (if that was a question here)

Comment: It depends on what you need as result and constraint on your query.

Comment: Thankyou for the answers. I forgot the final question. I am looking for the query which shows news from a certain state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use following query for join for tables:

```
mysql_query("select a.news_pk,a.user.a.description,a.buiding_pk,b.building_pk,b.area_pk,b.description,c.area_pk,c.state_pk,d.state_pk,d.name from news as a,buiding as b,area as c,states as d where a.buiding_pk=b.building_pk and b.area_pk=c.area_pk and c.state_pk=d.state_pk");
```

Comment: I will try if this works in a few minutes. Thankyou!

Comment: This is working fine. Now i just have to add several variables and conditions for showing only "state1" or "state2"...

Comment: Thankyou Chirag. This query is working perfectly for what I needed. I really apreciate your help!!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

It very much depends on what you want to do, inner join might be a good solution if it is what you are looking for. You can seel the difference between joins in this answer: [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thanks, i will read that for sure. I have to improve in MySQL!